# Data validation doesn't work in a calculated field in Access Form

Tags: ms-access, validationrules

I am having problem in data validation in one of my continuous subforms. There is a total score (TScore) field which is calculated (total of "Score" field) and a max score (MaxScore) field. I want the TScore value to never exceed my MaxScore value. I have tried validation rule (<=[MaxScore]) on TScore but nothing happens. I have also found out that validation rule doesn't work on calculated fields. I have also tried the Form_BeforeUpdate event like the following:

```
Private Sub Form_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
    
    If TScore > MaxScore Then
        MsgBox "The total score cannot be greater than max score.", vbOKOnly, "Warning!"
    
    End If
    
End Sub
```

[image: PICTURE]

But this don't work as well. Now I need some help on this.

Comment: "But this don't work" means what - error message, wrong result, nothing happens? What do you want to happen - delete a record, cancel data input? How is TScore calculated?

Comment: I meant to say "nothing happens" and the msgbox doesn't come up. TScore is the sum of the Score field.

Comment: What do you want to happen? Just a MsgBox? Code works for me.

Comment: You say you "want the TScore value to never exceed my MaxScore" - code presented will not accomplish that. You say TScore is the sum of Score but don't say where and how that calculation takes place. If Tscore is higher, do you want to cancel the record update? Use `Cancel = True`.

Comment: I have added a screenshot of the form in the post. Please check it.

Comment: Again, what do you want to happen? As I said, code works for me. Might post to a forum that allows attaching files and provide your db for analysis.

Comment: I want to prevent the total score to never exceed max score. When it happens at least show a msgbox (just like above) and cancel the record update if possible. The above code doesn't show a msgbox when total score exceeds max score like it supposed to.

Comment: Are you sure nothing happens? Have you set a breakpoint on the `If` line to even verify whether event triggers?

Comment: Sorry for late reply...Now Somehow it works but not always. I added `Me.Score.Value=""` before 'end if' of the code. When it exceeds the max score first time it the code doesn't trigger but if I change the value of "Score" then it triggers (even though the changed score value doesn't exceed the max score). It's very weird. So I had to reject this and I moved to Conditional formatting to let the user know the max score is exceeded. It doesn't accomplish the my initial goal and there is nothing else to do. Thanks anyway.